# Finding a series expansion for this integral, for large $\lambda > 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

Given the integral $$Z(\lambda ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} dx e^{- \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{\lambda}{4!} x^4} $$ in quantum field theory, I need to find a series expansion for $Z(\lambda)$ when $\lambda >> 1$, of the form $$ Z_N ( \lambda) = \sum_{n=0}^N d_n \lambda^{-(2n+1)/4}. $$

I was thinking of writing $e^{- \frac{\lambda}{4!} x^4} \approx 1 - \frac{ \lambda}{4!} x^4$, because only the first two terms will dominate when $\lambda$ is large. But this doesn't seem to give me the right expansion when I plug it in the integral and do the Gaussian integration.

Anyone has any ideas/advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks correct. Since you can expand the exponential function in terms of $\lambda$, and $\lambda$ is a factor independent of the integration, this is the expansion you are looking for. Maybe your calculation has an error?

Comment: What do you mean, expand the exponential in terms of $\lambda$? Can you show me how.

Comment: You already started it with $1-\frac{\lambda}{4!}x^4$. Just view $\lambda$ as a parameter and $\frac{x^4}{4!}$ as a constant for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, but I get an expansion in $\lambda$ when I do the full expansion. Not when I cut it at $- \lambda / 4! x^4$ as I did. And if I do the full expansion, nowhere in my argument I will use that $\lambda$ is large?

Comment: Oh sorry, you are right. I misread the question and was thinking of small $\lambda$. I don't know of a method to expand $e^{-\lambda}$ for large $\lambda$.

Comment: Let $\mu = \sqrt[4]{\lambda}$ and make the substitution $y = \mu x$.

Comment: I still don't see how that will help me. I then get the integral $Z(\mu) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int \frac{dy}{\mu} e^{- \frac{y^2}{\mu^2} \frac{1}{2} - \frac{y^4}{4!}}. $ Do I now expand the first exponential using the first two terms only?

Comment: @Kamil: you may want it or not, but $Z(\lambda)$ is related to a modified Bessel function of the second kind, so the coefficients of its asymptotic expansion are given by equation (4) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) and they are pretty complicated. For instance, $$ d_0 = \frac{3^{1/4}\Gamma(1/4)}{2^{3/4}\sqrt{\pi}}.$$ Actually $$Z(\lambda)\sim  \frac{3^{1/4}\Gamma(1/4)}{2^{3/4}\sqrt{\pi}\lambda^{1/4}}+\frac{3^{3/4}\Gamma(-1/4)}{4\cdot 2^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}\lambda}\quad\text{as }\lambda\to +\infty. $$

Comment: Ok thank you. But why did you delete your post before I had the chance to study it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the substitution $y=\frac{\lambda}{24}x^4$, we find that

\begin{align*}
&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left( -\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{\lambda}{24}x^4 \right) \, dx \\
&\hspace{4em} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^{3/4}} \left(\frac{6}{\lambda}\right)^{1/4} \exp\left( -\sqrt{\frac{6}{\lambda}y} - y \right) \, dx \\
&\hspace{4em} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \left(\frac{6}{\lambda}\right)^{\frac{2n+1}{4}} \int_{0}^{\infty} y^{\frac{n}{2}-\frac{3}{4}} e^{-y} \, dx \\
&\hspace{4em} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)}{n!} \left(\frac{6}{\lambda}\right)^{\frac{2n+1}{4}}.
\end{align*}

So you may let

$$ d_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)}{n!} \cdot 6^{\frac{2n+1}{4}}. $$